# Laravel Observer Updating/Updated

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, observer-pattern, observers

I am not sure how best to do this. I need access to `is_dirty()` to check if specific fields were changed which needs to be done in the 'Updating' method in the observer. But I only want to act on it if the update is successful.

If there a way within the 'Updating' method to tell it to try to save the changes and then see if it was successful?

If not, what would be the best way to pair Updating and Updated? Would I just save a cache value in Updating specifying if the relevant fields were modified, then pull that cache value in Updated? Or would there be a better way?

Comment: Please share a simple code to better understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something along these lines:

```
class ModelObserver
{   
    public function updated(Model $model)
    {
        /**
         * Listening inside 'updated' since we only care about model 
         * updated which have already happened
         */
        if ($model->wasChanged('my-special-field')) {
            // Do something...
        } 
    }
}
```

You can read more about the `wasChanged` method [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#examining-attribute-changes).

Comment: You should update the if statement in your code block to say 'wasChanged'. Currently it says 'hasChanged', which I don't think is a valid method. Thanks for your answer!